# How to structure Ruby on Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm curious to learn Ruby and Ruby on Rails. I have previous experience with PHP and some basic C/Objective C and Java.

I have done a couple of 'Get started with Rails' tutorials and want to try do create a complete site now. I do have some questions.

Is the entire website an app? I mean, sure, the simple 'blog-with-comments' examples fit in a single app. But what if you want more? Say, a forum, a blog, community, shop, task manager and so on (only random examples here... :) ).

Should I split these things into different 'apps' or not? I would still need them to communicate with each other and share user data and so on...

Any ideas?

Regards
Linus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, your core competency as a rails app -- that which you provide the most value for your users. You can then supplement from there, so your support section might be GetSatisfaction and live on support.yourdomain.com.

Your online shop could be a link to your shopify page at shop.yourdomain.com, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And if I decide to develop the shop and forum (or whatever it may be) I should create separate apps for those? Of course I would do like you propose if I use 3rd-party apps but I'm talking about my own development here. I just think it's a bit hard to decide how much to put in one app and when to separate them. The user authentication would still need to be the same so I need to make the apps share some data. Simple in RoR?

Comment: @linus -- centralized authentication isn't really simple in any platform... If you are developing the code, have it be in the same project.